# Choosing directories to output by timestamp named directories

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of directories that are named according to some timestamp. For example

```
/d_20141123_0435
/d_20141123_0436
/d_20141123_0437  <--- start
/d_20141123_0438
/d_20141123_0439
/d_20141123_0440
...
...
...
/d_20141124_0438
/d_20141124_0439
/d_20141124_0440  <-- end
```

I was wondering if there is a bash command that would output only certain dates I want. For example if I only wanted the output of directories between `20141123-0437` to `20141124-0440`

`ls (logic) >> output.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ls` command does not have such a functionality but you can use a simple script. Output of `ls` should no be parsed but if you really want to use it, replace `*` by `$(ls)`.

If the boundaries should not be included:

```
after=d_20141123_0437
before=d_20141124_0440
for a in * ; do
    if test "$a" \> "$after" && test "$a" \< "$before" ; then
        echo "$a"
    fi
done >> output.text
```

If they should be included:

```
after=d_20141123_0437
before=d_20141124_0440
for a in * ; do
    if { test "$a" \> "$after" && test "$a" \< "$before" ; } ||
            test "$a" = "$after" || test "$a" = "$before" ; then
        echo "$a"
    fi
done >> output.text
```

Both scripts can be on a single line if you replace newlines after commands by `;`.

Comment: This is probably the most portable script which would work on old shells also +1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these directories in a file like shown you can use this awk:

```
awk -F_ -v s1='20141123-0437' -v s2='20141124-0440' 'BEGIN{
   split(s1, a, "-");
   split(s2, b, "-");
   start = a[1]a[2];
   end = b[1]b[2];
}
int($2$3) >= start && int($2$3) <= end' file

/d_20141123_0437  <--- start
/d_20141123_0438
/d_20141123_0439
/d_20141123_0440
/d_20141124_0438
/d_20141124_0439
/d_20141124_0440  <-- end
```

Comment: The downvote is not from me. I did not thoroughly check your script before but now I see there is a bug there. Anyway I think it is a good idea to use `awk` for this problem. ------ The operator `+` you are using is performing a simple arithmetic addition but the operands do not represent the same thing (they are not of the same magnitude). ------ One possibility to correct the problem is to adjust the magnitude: `10000*$2+$3`. The other, shorter possibility is to use a string concatenation instead of arithmetic addition: `$1$2`.

Comment: @pabouk: Reason why `+` is also working (and output is also shown) because date is written as `yyyymmdd_hhmm` so sum is basically e.g. `20141124 + 0440` and being compared to `20141124-0440`, there replacing `-` by `+` so it becomes `20141124 + 0440`.

Comment: You are comparing numbers created the same way (`$2+$3` and `x[1]+x[2]`). I think that is clear and that is not the problem I was trying to point out. The problem is how you create the numbers. You are adding different things together - date and time. That is wrong. ------ Practical example: Let's compare the fourth and third line from the end of the list your way: `awk -F_ '{print $2,$3,$2+$3}' <<<$'d_20141123_0440\nd_20141124_0438'`. You see that the order is the opposite than it should be.

Comment: To show the problem directly on your script and the original data. Let's set the end value to the fourth directory from the end of the list: `s2=20141123-0440`. The resulting list wrongly ends at the second directory from the end. ------- To resolve the problem you can just take all the `+` operators away as I wrote in my first comment. (I wrongly wrote `$1$2` instead of `$2$3` there.)

Comment: Thanks so much @pabouk for your valuable comments. I have updated awk script based on that.

Comment: @anubhava i was the one who downvoted, i was doing something else though and forgot to leave a comment. I can't actually remember what the downvote was for and looking at the script now it looks fine. If you edit the answer i'll remove the vote :)

Comment: @Jidder: No issues at all, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, **brace expansion** is your friend:

```
ls d_20141123_0{437..440} >> output.text
```

**brace expansion** works by providing a sequence of numbers between `{start..end}`. So you can form any filename match you need by replacing the number sequence you are interested in with a **brace expansion**. In your case `d_20141123_0{start..end}`

Comment: Is not this something different than Liondancer asked for? Brace expansion generates a list of strings regardless of existence of the files/directories. ------ You can use something like `[d]_20141123_0{start..end}` but in `bash` you must enable `shopt -s nullglob`. Unfortunately This would not be very portable.

Comment: My friend, as with other tasks, there is more than one way to skin this cat. Chose whichever one suits your liking. The question is tagged **bash**, this is what **brace expansion** in **bash** was intended to do. Porability from **bash** to **bash** does not present a problem.

Comment: I do not think we know each other. --- You skipped the main point which is in the first two sentences of my comment. Portability was just an additional minor note almost hidden at the end :)

Comment: If needling other people about issues not asked for in the question is what makes you happy, feel free. Otherwise, please try an limit your comments and critiques to the current question. Your answer will get chosen just as often.